# What is the solution to $\frac1{a^2 +2} + \frac1{b^2 +2} + \frac1{c^2 +2} \le \frac{\sqrt2}{2}\frac{\sqrt a+\sqrt b+\sqrt c}{\sqrt{abc}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

one of my friends asked me if I could solve him a mathematics problem.
It looks like this:
$$\frac1{a^2 +2} + \frac1{b^2 +2} + \frac1{c^2 +2} \le \frac{\sqrt2}{2}\frac{\sqrt a+\sqrt b+\sqrt c}{\sqrt{abc}}$$
As I think it looks like an inequality between means, hope it helps.
And sorry for my bad english by the way. :)

Comment: Please check to make sure I wrote your formula correctly.

Comment: Do you want to prove this inequality or try to find when this inequality will be OK? if it is first case,then it is not true. if it is second case, it is complex as there are 3 varies.

Comment: a necessary condition is $c\le (\dfrac{a(a^2+2)^2}{3})^{\frac{1}{3}}$ if $a\le b \le c$

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality, we assume that $0 < a \leq b \leq c.$ Then, by AM-GM we have, 
$$
\frac{a^2 + (\sqrt{2})^2}{2} \geq a\sqrt{2}, 
$$
and so 
$$
\frac{1}{a^2 + 2} + \frac{1}{b^2+2} + \frac{1}{c^2+2} \leq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\left( \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c} \right).
$$
Now, 
$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{c}} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{b}} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}},
$
so using the rearrangement inequalities, and adding, we obtain the desired result.

Comment: there is problem.your RHS is not always < RHS(original),take $a=1,b=c=25$,your RHS=$\dfrac{27\sqrt{2}}{100}>\dfrac{22\sqrt{2}}{100} $ of original.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that the rearrangement inequality does not give exactly what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

The starting inequality is obviously wrong!. Try $a=0$ and $b=c=1$.

Comment: There's a missing condition here that $a,b,c > 0$.

Comment: Aren't $a,b,c$ implicitly taken to be positive, since the denominator of the right-hand side would otherwise be undefined and (real) square roots can only exist for nonnegative numbers?

Comment: @A.Sh It's exactly, which I say. We need to prove something, which wrong for $a=0$.

Answer (score 0):

@michael Rozenberg: Let's bury this one for good by presenting a point with all positive $a,b,c$ such that the inequality is violated.

Take
$$
a = 25\\
b=25\\
c= \frac{59}{81} \\
\frac{1}{a^2+2}+\frac{1}{b^2+2}+\frac{1}{c^2+2} = \frac{4146953}{10410081}
> 0.3983 \\
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\frac{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}}{\sqrt{abc}}=
\frac{59+90\sqrt{59}}{2950}\sqrt{2} < 0.3597
\\\mbox{LHS } > 0.39 > 0.36 > \mbox{ RHS}
$$
which violates the inequality.